# Equivalent of "whereKey:doesNotMatchKey:inQuery:" in C#

Tags: c#, parse-platform

**Update:** Version 1.3.4 of the .NET SDK fixed this issue!

I'm porting an iOS Parse project to Unity (C#) and I have troubles findes an C# eqivalent for

```
PFQuery -whereKey:doesNotMatchKey:inQuery:
```

There is

```
ParseQuery<T> WhereDoesNotMatchQuery<TOther>(string key,
                                             ParseQuery<TOther> query)
```

But as far as I understand, it searches for the same key in both queries, whereas I would need something like:

```
WhereDoesNotMatchQuery(key: "id", otherKey: "otherId", query: subquery)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filed this as a bug and got a [response](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/parse-developers/-nBR7OKgBRg) from parse that they are working on adding that missing API to the C# library.